# Django Celery Beat

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery, django-celery

My times keep drifting with `django-celery-beat`, and seems to be related to the `last_run_date` being wrong. The time drift gets worse over time and seems to be related to

Will resetting the last_run_at on every run fix this?

```
>>> from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, PeriodicTasks
>>> PeriodicTask.objects.all().update(last_run_at=None)
>>> PeriodicTasks.changed()
```

Comment: Generally speaking, celery strongly recommends using cron instead of periodic.

Comment: @2ps wouldn't this be a problem if multiple users each have many of their own periodic tasks we create for them?

Comment: Essentially the issue is this, celery makes this guarantee for a periodic task :  a subsequent task will run no sooner than t + N (where t is the time the previous task *ended*, and N is the period).  Thus, even under perfect circumstances tasks will drift by the amount of time it takes to execute a task.